# Too many Looper class instances error: Repeating Alarm signaling WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm receiving the following "Looper class instance count" error in my Android app (running on a phone running KitKat, v4.4.2):

```
D/ActivityThread: SVC-STOP_SERVICE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@42137070
D/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service: CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@41fc59a0 className=com.floor2labs.perp.WakefulMqttService packageName=org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample intent=null}
D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=128KB
D/dalvikvm: create new thread
D/dalvikvm: new thread created
D/dalvikvm: update thread list
D/dalvikvm: threadid=15: interp stack at 0x566f9000
D/dalvikvm: threadid=15: created from interp
D/dalvikvm: threadid=15: adding to list
D/dalvikvm: start new thread
D/dalvikvm: threadid=15: notify debugger
D/dalvikvm: threadid=15 (IntentService[WakefulMqttService]): calling run()
E/Looper: WARNING: The Looper class instance count has over a limit(100). There should be some leakage of Looper or HandlerThread.
E/Looper: Looper class instance count = 153
E/Looper: Current Thread Name: IntentService[WakefulMqttService]
I/System.out: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxPriority=10]
I/System.out:     Thread[main,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[Binder_1,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[Binder_2,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[Thread-1989,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[Thread-1990,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[MQTT Rec: a06a1ecf0542,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[MQTT Snd: a06a1ecf0542,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[MQTT Call: a06a1ecf0542,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[Binder_3,5,main]
I/System.out:     Thread[IntentService[WakefulMqttService],5,main]
W/System.err: java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:489)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:104)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:85)
W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:54)D/ActivityThread: SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@41fc59a0 className=com.floor2labs.perp.WakefulMqttService packageName=org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample intent=null}
D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.floor2labs.perp.WakefulMqttService@41e9e9a8, flags=0, startId=1
D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@41fc59a0 startId=1 args=Intent { cmp=org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample/com.floor2labs.perp.WakefulMqttService (has extras) }}
V/INFO: wake-up for mqtt alarm
D/ActivityThread: SVC-Destroying service: com.floor2labs.perp.WakefulMqttService@41e9e9a8
D/ActivityThread: SVC-STOP_SERVICE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@41fc59a0
D/dalvikvm: threadid=15: exiting
D/dalvikvm: threadid=15: detach (group=0x4190dce0)
D/dalvikvm: threadid=15: removing from list
D/dalvikvm: threadid=15: bye!
```

The error comes from one of two similar services, either `WakefulMqttService` or `WakefulPingService` that are started by a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` that runs when an Alarm is fired:

The Alarm:

```
public static void scheduleMqttAlarm(Context context){

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent nextIntent = new Intent(context, MqttAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10 * 1000, alarmIntent);
}
```

The WakefulBroadcastReceiver referenced in the alarm above:

```
public class MqttAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, WakefulMqttService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);

        //schedule the next alarm
        MainService.scheduleMqttAlarm(context);

    } 
}
```

And finally, the IntentService started above:

```
public class WakefulMqttService extends IntentService {

    public static Vibrator vibrator;

    public WakefulMqttService(String name) {
    super(name);
    }

    public WakefulMqttService() {
        super("WakefulMqttService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.v("INFO", "wake-up for mqtt alarm");
        Intent buttonIntent = new Intent("mqttAlarmReceivedEvent");
        buttonIntent.putExtra("alarm", "mqtt");
             LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).sendBroadcast(buttonIntent);

        MqttAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

I believe I've followed all of the suggestions in the Android Developer's example for a WakefulBroadcastReceiver (link: [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html))

However, it appears none of the instances that get created with these alarms are getting closed properly.  There was a similar question posted from a couple years ago, but it didn't receive any answers.  I'd appreciate any help on solving this problem.

Comment: Why do you even use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` here? You could just use `PendingIntent.getService` and skip the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` entirely.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: The OP is using `AlarmManager`. Hence, `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is a well-regarded pattern for handling those events.

Comment: Temporarily comment out your `LocalBroadcastManager` work, and see if that clears up the problem. My guess is that it will.

Comment: @CommonsWare - no, it isn't useful for `AlarmManager`. `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is only useful when you *need* a `BroadcastReceiver` (such as when receiving a system broadcast and then reliably forwarding it to a `Service`). It is always more efficient to start only a single component, skipping the intermediate `BroadcastReceiver`. This also skips the reliability problem entirely as the device no longer has a chance to go to sleep between the start of your `BroadcastReceiver` and the start of your `Service`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: We were told, by Dianne Hackborn, years ago, that the *only* guarantee with `*_WAKEUP` alarms is *if* the `PendingIntent` is a broadcast, *then* `AlarmManager` will keep the device awake long enough for `onReceive()` to complete. For anything else (including services), `AlarmManager` will not keep the device awake, and so if the device falls asleep before your component gets invoked and you can grab a `WakeLock`, tough. That's why I wrote `WakefulIntentService` and AFAIK is why Google wrote `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`: to wrap up this pattern.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Now, it is entirely possible that Dianne was wrong, despite the fact that adopting her pattern greatly increased `AlarmManager` reliability. Or, it is entirely possible that Android changed since then, and now we have more guarantees (e.g., `onStartCommand()` will be called with a system-supplied `WakeLock`, allowing us to grab our own before returning). AFAIK, none of this is documented.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: FWIW, [here is the discussion from 2010 on this](http://androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/44771.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks, I'll try it and post back.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I tried commenting out the `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).sendBroadcast(buttonIntent);` line in the wakeful service, but I'm still seeing the same error.  I'm going to edit my post above to show more of the log before the Looper warning.